deploy smart contract into PoA private ethereum blockchain got error: 0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed
When deploying a smart contract to a PoA consensus Ethereum private chain, it always results in an error: "0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed." Upon checking the block information, it was discovered that the deployment failed due to running out of gas. Even after adjusting the gasLimit, the deployment still failed.
genesis.json like :
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 377777,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "constantinopleBlock": 0,
        "petersburgBlock": 0,
        "istanbulBlock": 0,
        "berlinBlock": 0,
        "clique": {
            "period": 10,
            "epoch": 30000
        }
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "8000000",
    "extradata": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000618C92D30E4a7B21A0D00DC7f5038024752ADFD50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
        "618C92D30E4a7B21A0D00DC7f5038024752ADFD5": {
            "balance": "100000000000000000000"
        },
        "4C8DEE4b7062f10C9D506688c418f1d90654ff86": {
            "balance": "100000000000000000000"
        }
    }
}

and the smart contract :
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Simple {
    function getValue() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}


Considering that it might be due to the EVM, the contract was successfully deployed after changing the Solidity compiler version in Remix. The geth 1.13.15 client uses the Istanbul EVM version by default

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
